# Python: Is there a way to use the range as the output name in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am searching for a was to use the range as the output name in a for loop.  I can think of other ways to do this, but this is for a class, so I am certain I am overlooking something simple.  In the simplified code below, I want the output to be something like:

"t1 = [[ 0.5  1.   1.5]
 [ 2.   2.5  3. ]]"

"t2 = [[ 3.5  4.   4.5]
 [ 5.   5.5  6. ]]"

```
t1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
t2 = np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])

for set in [t1,t2]:
   out = set/2
   print(out)
```

Comment: You want the variable name to be printed or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Variable *names* do not exist outside the source code itself.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not sufficiently specific: I am given a line equivalent to: "for set in [t1,t2]:" and need to assign the names "t1" and t2" to the results. Apologies, my answer is oddly formatted because this editor will not accept line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
t = {}
t[1] = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
t[2] = np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])

t = {k: v/2 for k, v in t.items()}

{1: array([[ 0.5,  1. ,  1.5],
       [ 2. ,  2.5,  3. ]]),
 2: array([[ 3.5,  4. ,  4.5],
       [ 5. ,  5.5,  6. ]])}
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was not sufficiently specific:  I am given a line equivalent to:     for set in [t1,t2]:  and need to assign the names "t1" and t2" to the results.  My answer is oddly formatted because this editor will not accept line breaks.

Comment: Updated. It looks like you want to provide numeric labels to arrays. A dictionary, as above, is suitable for this.

Comment: That is quite elegant!  I am not certain that is what they had in mind, but I will play around with your solution and see if I can make it fit their constraints.  Thank you!

Comment: Your updated code does not appear anymore (?)  I am posting here in case someone else has the same problem:

Comment: t = {}
    t[1] = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
    t[2] = np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])

    t = {k: v/2 for k, v in t.items()}

Comment: Beware: dicts are not ordered (well they technically are in py3.6 but that's an implementation detail - they are still specified as being an _unordered_ collection of key:value pairs).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers. agreed. for ordering, you can easily sort keys and `print` accordingly. For such labeling, though, dictionaries are the way to go.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis sometimes you can't rely on natural sort and want insertion ordering instead. In this case `collections.OrderedDict` is your friend - or you can just use a list of `(key, value)` tuples if you don't need O(1) access.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for ?

```
t1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
t2 = np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])


def print_list(name, value):
    print("{n} = {v}".format(n=name, v=str(value).replace('\n', '')))

>>> print_list("t2", t2)
"t2 = [[ 7  8  9] [10 11 12]]"
```

Or of course, with that divided by 2 specification

```
>>> print_list("t2", t2/2)
"t2 = [[ 3.5  4.   4.5] [ 5.   5.5  6. ]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Q&D:

```
t1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
t2 = np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])

for i, set in enumerate([t1,t2], 1):
   out = set/2
   print("t{} = {}".format(i, out))
```

a bit cleaner

```
t1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
t2 = np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])

for name, set in zip(["t1", "t2"], [t1, t2]):
   out = set/2
   print("{} = {}".format(name, out))
```

even cleaner:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
sets = OrderedDict(
    t1=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]),
    t2=np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
    )

for name, set in sets.items():
   out = set/2
   print("{} = {}".format(name, out))
```

I could go on with quite a few other ways to skin this cat, but really the "right" solution depends on the real context and use case.

As a side note: avoid using "set" as an identifier, as it will shadows the builtin `set` type. Ok not much of a problem in a three-lines function, but it's still considered bad (or debatable at least) practice.